# How to build a Flash program to always have right-click > "Show All" enabled?

Tags: flash

I'm making a FlashDevelop/Flixel game and I need it to run in fullscreen. Everything is set up, the only problem is that everytime I run it, I have to right click and click "Show All".
There must be a way to set this property/parameter in the code, but I can't find it.

Comment: I don't think these settings exist in FlashDevelop?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was thinking on flash... I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I needed:

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;    
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was now searching for hours, until i realized, it does not have anything to do with scaling but with zooming. Then I found this post:

http://www.webreference.com/js/tips/010605.html

After trying arround with Zoom() I found out, that `$("object#flash").Zoom(0)` does the same as right-click -> show all

Hope I could help others with the same Problem

**EDIT:**
Oh, its important, to execute the Zoom thing after the flash was loaded. Because onload does not work on objects or embeds, use this:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('flash').Zoom(0)>
```